# How to lookup and return multiple values alternating (50/50)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a sets of 2 break times and i want to lookup values for a big schedule and getting one of two types of break time with a 50/50 ratio.

**Example**

[image: Example]

I know how to vlookup, but it always returns me only the first or second value, not alternating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood clearly and not mistaken with the required output, then you might need this as an output using the following formula: <kbd>DOUBLE VLOOKUP( )</kbd> with an <kbd>IF( )</kbd> Logic with <kbd>COUNTIF( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2,VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,1),VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,0))
```

---

Formula needs to be filled down for the rest of the cells. Also make sure to change the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

We can make it bit shorter here is how. <kbd>IF( )</kbd> Logic with <kbd>COUNTIF( )</kbd> is used in for the optional param <kbd>[range_lookup]</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2,1,0))
```

---

### Revised Approach Two :

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2)
```

---

### Revised Solution Based On OP's Comments:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$19,D2)<=2,
  VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>1),
  VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2)),"")
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: It works almost perfect, only downside is that if i have only 2 people on a shift it doesn`t bring diferent break time. But it`s almost perfect for me. Thanks a lot. @Mayukh Bhattacharya.

Comment: If let`s say i have only 2  8 Shift - one should be 8:00 - 11:00 and the other should be 8:30 - 11:30

Comment: @GeorgianStoica this would do the trick try this one then: `=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$16,D2)<=2,VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>1,1,0)),VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2,1,0))),"")`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. Really apreciate the help.

Comment: I made it shorter try this : `=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$19,D2)<=2,VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>1),VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$9,2,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)>2)),"")`

Comment: Sorry to come back to this, after aplying to my schedule, it looks like if there are more than 4 shifts, first two get the first "break type", and all the rest get the "second break type" - so they are not 50/50 split.

Comment: The result  is not 50/50 rate

Comment: @Blackcat let me know what you mean by the rate is not 50/50. Have you read and understood the question yet. OP repeatedly makes changes to their post, and this is not first time they does it

Comment: To be fair to my cause - i said i looked after a 50/50 ratio, but don`t wanna be rude or anything, so i`m gonna work with what u guys already ofered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're repeating the range 2 times and the outcome is sorted by shift, then breaktimes.

You could use VSTACK and SORT to get the desired result, in this case `=SORT(VSTACK(A2:B9,A2:B9),{1,2})`

If you want a changeable number of repeats, you could make use of REDUCE:

```
=LET(range,  A2:B9,
     rw,     ROWS(range),
     repeat, 2,
SORT(REDUCE(range,SEQUENCE(repeat-1),
     LAMBDA(r,rpt,
            VSTACK(r,TAKE(r,rw)))),
     {1,2}))
```

You can then change `repeat` to whatever number of times you need it repeated.

*I see Excel 2013 is tagged. This requires Office 365. For older Excel refer to Mayukh's answer*